# PHPMailer for Gmail action not being taken

Tags: php, smtp, gmail, phpmailer

Does anyone knows what is wrong with this code ? I am pretty new to PHP and I am having problems when trying to send contact mails from the web page.

The action seems to be executed but the mail in fact is not sent.

```html
<?php

$Nombre = $_POST['Nombre'];
$Apellido = $_POST['Apellido'];
$Correo = $_POST['Correo'];
$Numero = $_POST['Numero'];

require_once('PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');

$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth= true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->Port = '587';

$mail->isHTML(true);

$mail->setFrom($Correo, $Nombre);
$mail->AddAddress('');
$mail->AddReplyTo($Correo, $Nombre);

$mail->Username = '';
$mail->Password = '';

$mail->Subject = '';
$mail->Body = 'l';


$mail->Send();

?>
```

Comment: When you run the code, are you adding the username and password of the gmail account that you are sending from? Also switch SSL to TSL

Comment: You're using a very old version of PHPMailer, there are quite a few mistakes in here, and you have no error checking. Rather than waste time pointing them all out, I suggest you [update to the latest version](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer), and start again basing your code on [the gmail example provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail.phps) and [the example contact form](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/contactform.phps).